# Expand collapse a layout in recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view which has header element and child element at starting time the visibility of child element is gone. I want that when I clicked on header element suppose position zero child elements of that position should be visible (mean expand) I achieve this successfully. The only problem that I am facing is that when I clicked the same position again I want to collapse the same view.

My recycler view onBingViewHolder logic is given below:

```
holder.doc_type.setText(docDatalist.get(position).getDocTypeDesc());

    if (position == expandedPosition )
    {
            holder.recyclerViewImages.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imagerequestserver(docDatalist.get(expandedPosition), vinappserial, holder);
            holder.iconexpandCollapse.setImageResource(R.mipmap.expand_4);
        }


     else {
        holder.recyclerViewImages.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.iconexpandCollapse.setImageResource(R.mipmap.expand);

    }
    holder.myDocumentListCollapse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            
            if (expandedPosition >= 0) {

                    int prev = expandedPosition;
                    holder.recyclerViewImages.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                notifyItemChanged(prev);

            }else {
                expandedPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                notifyItemChanged(expandedPosition);
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: I suggest to implement this using a [`SparseBooleanArray`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseBooleanArray.html). The logic is that each time an item is expanded you simply get the position of the item and use it to make the boolean **true** inside your SparseBooleanArray and **false** for collapsed state.

Comment: I don't see `shouldExpand` being used anywhere...

Comment: @Belladonna sorry I forget to remove it.

Comment: If you are trying to expand/collapse a layout in RecyclerView, I think there is a library that is popular for doing that. [this](https://github.com/skydoves/ExpandableLayout) and [this](https://github.com/cachapa/ExpandableLayout)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add manually add position array which was clicked and then after check its position in viewHolder;

Provide collapse Position List in your constructor

```
positionSet = new ArrayList<>();
```

Add and remove appropriate position on Header Click listener  click event:

```
 public void onClick(View view) {


                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if(positionSet.contains(position)){

                    positionSet.remove((Integer)position);
                }else {
                    positionSet.add(position);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
```

Manage to notify in onBindViewHolder

```
 if(positionSet.contains(position)){
        //visible
    }else {
        //gone
    }
```

Comment: From where you are getting expandedPosition?